# How to sum array of numbers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, math, sum

I have an array of integers.

For example:

```
array = [123,321,12389]
```

Is there any nice way to get the sum of them?

I know, that

```
sum = 0
array.each { |a| sum+=a }
```

would work.

Comment: Please note that Ruby 2.4+ has `array.sum`

Comment: Ruby 2.6 does not have it. Ruby giveth, Ruby taketh away, it seems.

Comment: @Lori hmm ? [link](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Array.html#method-i-sum)

Comment: Sorry. At that time I mistakenly believed I was using 2.6 because of a rbenv slip-up on my part.

Comment: If you need to supply a default value for when the `Array` is empty, like if you want to return a `Money` object instead of an `Integer`, you can do something like `array.sum( 0.to_money( "USD" ) )`.

Answer (score 648, accepted):

Try this:

```
array.inject(0){ |sum, x| sum + x }
```

[See Ruby's Enumerable Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

(note: the `0` base case is needed so that `0` will be returned on an empty array instead of `nil`)

Comment: jorney's `array.inject(:+)` is more efficient.

Comment: `array.inject(:+)` seems to cause **trouble** in Ruby 1.8.6 Exceptions " LocalJumpError : no block given" might pop up.

Comment: In rails `array.sum` might give you sum of the array values.

Comment: In most cases, I prefer to use `reduce`, which is an alias of `inject` (as in `array.reduce( :+ )`).

Comment: @Boris Also, Rubycop will warn you for using `inject` rather than `reduce`.

Answer (score 860):

**For ruby >= 2.4** you can use [sum](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sum):

`array.sum`

**For ruby < 2.4** you can use [inject](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject):

```
array.inject(0, :+)
```

Note: the `0` base case is needed otherwise `nil` will be returned on empty arrays:

```
> [].inject(:+)
nil
> [].inject(0, :+)
0
```

Comment: How can I use this way to sum a attribute from object. My array [product1, product2] I want to sum product1.price + product2.price. Is it possible using array.inject(:+)?

Comment: Pablo: You can do: array.map{|p| p.price}.inject(+:)

Comment: You can use a similar trick with the map method: array.map(&:price).inject(:+)

Comment: `array.map(&:price).inject(0, :+)` is a bit safer. It makes sure that if you have an empty list you get **0** instead of **nil**.

Comment: using array.map(...).inject(...) is inefficient, you will iterate through all data twice. Try  `array.inject(0) { |sum, product| sum += product.price }`

Comment: @everett1992 In most cases, this is probably a premature optimisation.

Comment: @everett1992 and as it turns out, not even an optimisation at all. Doing it in two stages is consistently faster for me. https://gist.github.com/cameron-martin/b907ec43a9d8b9303bdc

Comment: @everett1992 `inject` handles forwarding the result itself. you should write `sum + product.price` instead of `sum += product.price`. If you really want to build an object by yourself (e.g. some array), you should consider [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object)

Comment: @PabloCantero for ruby >= 2.4, [sum](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sum) works like this: `array.sum(&:price)` (you can also use the pretzel-colon like Johnf suggested with `.map`. In rails btw [the `sum` method already exists like forever](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/sum).

Answer (score 305):

```
array.reduce(0, :+)
```

While equivalent to `array.inject(0, :+)`, the term **reduce** is entering a more common vernacular with the rise of [MapReduce programming models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

**inject**, **reduce**, **fold**, **accumulate**, and **compress** are all synonymous as a class of [folding functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_%28higher-order_function%29). I find consistency across your code base most important, but since various communities tend to prefer one word over another, it’s nonetheless useful to know the alternatives.

To emphasize the map-reduce verbiage, here’s a version that is a little bit more forgiving on what ends up in that array.

```
array.map(&:to_i).reduce(0, :+)
```

Some additional relevant reading:

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Comment: I agree, `reduce` tells me more of what the function does, but `inject` does sound much cooler.

Comment: The one comment I would make is that `reduce` and `map` as higher-order functions predate MapReduce. The inspiration runs the other way. And in the MapReduce sense, it's a somewhat different operation than a simple functional reduce, having implications for how different machines communicate.

Comment: Ken Iverson introduced the operator / called "reduction operator" in the programming language APL.

Source: Iverson, Kenneth. 1962. A Programming Language. Wiley.

Another source: "Notation as a Tool of Thought", 1979 ACM Turing Award Lecture, Kenneth E. Iverson, http://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=1283935&type=pdf

Answer (score 118):

Alternatively (just for comparison), if you have Rails installed (actually just ActiveSupport):

```
require 'activesupport'
array.sum
```

Comment: Newer versions of activesupport don't actually load all extensions by default.  You'll want to either require just the sum module: `require 'active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb'`, or require all of active support: `require 'active_support/all'`.  More about it here: [API Docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)

Comment: Never mind that `activesupport` is a *massive* dependency to drag into a project to go from `array.inject(:+)` to `array.sum`.

Comment: Nitpick to an otherwise good comment: it should be `require 'active_support/core_ext/enumerable'` without the `.rb` suffix, since that's added implicitly.

Answer (score 97):

For Ruby >=2.4.0 you can use `sum` from Enumerables.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].sum
```

It is dangerous to mokeypatch base classes.  If you like danger and using an older version of Ruby, you could add `#sum` to the `Array` class:

```
class Array
  def sum
    inject(0) { |sum, x| sum + x }
  end
end
```

Comment: Monkeypatching base classes is not nice.

Comment: The point he is making is that you don't need to do the Monkey Patch for Ruby >= 2.4, and that monkey patching is dangerous, and that you can now sum enumerables natively, but there is also a way to backport the functionality.

Comment: As noted, [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) (and [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum)) were introduced in Ruby v2.4. Importantly, they do not have the same behavior as your `Array#sum`; namely, they take an optional argument and an optional block. Defining `Array#sum` as you have would result in an exception being raised wherever `sum` appeared in the code with an argument or block.

Comment: If you need to supply a default value for when the `Array` is empty, like if you want to return a `Money` object instead of an `Integer`, you can do something like `array.sum( 0.to_money( "USD" ) )`.

Answer (score 51):

## New for Ruby 2.4.0

You can use the aptly named method `Enumerable#sum`. It has a lot of advantages over `inject(:+)` but there are some important notes to read at the end as well.

### Examples

#### Ranges

```
(1..100).sum
#=> 5050
```

#### Arrays

```
[1, 2, 4, 9, 2, 3].sum
#=> 21

[1.9, 6.3, 20.3, 49.2].sum
#=> 77.7
```

### Important note

This method is not equivalent to `#inject(:+)`. For example

```
%w(a b c).inject(:+)
#=> "abc"
%w(a b c).sum
#=> TypeError: String can't be coerced into Integer
```

Also,

```
(1..1000000000).sum
#=> 500000000500000000 (execution time: less than 1s)
(1..1000000000).inject(:+)
#=> 500000000500000000 (execution time: upwards of a minute)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449844/5021321) for more information on why `sum` is like this.

Comment: If you need to supply a default value for when the `Array` is empty, like if you want to return a `Money` object instead of an `Integer`, you can do something like `array.sum( 0.to_money( "USD" ) )`.

Comment: This answer is deprecated. In ruby2.6.6 for example, you **can** do `%w(a b c).sum # => "abc"`

Comment: Note that if you are doing math, an `Array` of `Float` or `BigDecimal` called by `.sum` will convert them back to `Integer`, breaking your math!  You need to call `foo.sum.to_f` to preserve the Float.

Answer (score 22):

Ruby 2.4+ / Rails - `array.sum` i.e. `[1, 2, 3].sum # => 6`

Ruby pre 2.4 - `array.inject(:+)` or `array.reduce(:+)`

*Note: The `#sum` method is a new addition to 2.4 for `enumerable` so you will now be able to use `array.sum` in pure ruby, not just Rails.

Answer (score 19):

Just for the sake of diversity, you can also do this if your array is not an array of numbers, but rather an array of objects that have properties that are numbers (e.g. amount):

```
array.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x.amount}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to doing: `array.map(&:amount).inject(0, :+)`. See other answers.

Comment: In a way, yes. However, using `map` then `inject` requires you to loop through the array twice: once to create a new array, the other to sum the members. This method is slightly more verbose, but also more efficient.

Comment: Apparently it is not more efficient, see https://gist.github.com/cameron-martin/b907ec43a9d8b9303bdc - credit to the comments in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538949/1028679

Comment: @RichardJones or just `array.sum(&:amount)` as of today (using ruby >= 2.4 or rails).

Answer (score 18):

ruby 1.8.7 way is the following:

```
array.inject(0, &:+)
```

Comment: If you read my 2011 comment, and it's still relevant as you're using 1.8.6, please upgrade!

Answer (score 6):

Ruby 2.4.0 is released, and it has an [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method. So you can do

```
array.sum
```

Examples from the docs:

```
{ 1 => 10, 2 => 20 }.sum {|k, v| k * v }  #=> 50
(1..10).sum                               #=> 55
(1..10).sum {|v| v * 2 }                  #=> 110
```

Answer (score 4):

Also allows for `[1,2].sum{|x| x * 2 } == 6`:

```
# http://madeofcode.com/posts/74-ruby-core-extension-array-sum
class Array
  def sum(method = nil, &block)
    if block_given?
      raise ArgumentError, "You cannot pass a block and a method!" if method
      inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + yield(i) }
    elsif method
      inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + i.send(method) }
    else
      inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + i }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

for array with nil values we can do compact and then inject the sum
ex-

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,12,23.45,nil,23,nil]
puts a.compact.inject(:+)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

```
    [1] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4].sum
    => 10
    [2] pry(main)> [].sum
    => 0
    [3] pry(main)> [1,2,3,5,nil].sum
    TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer
```

**Method 2:**

```
   [24] pry(main)> [].inject(:+)
   => nil
   [25] pry(main)> [].inject(0, :+)
   => 0
   [4] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,5].inject(0, :+)
   => 15
   [5] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,nil].inject(0, :+)
   TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer
   from (pry):5:in `+'
```

**Method 3:**

```
   [6] pry(main)> [1,2,3].reduce(:+)
   => 6
   [9] pry(main)> [].reduce(:+)
   => nil
   [7] pry(main)> [1,2,nil].reduce(:+)
   TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer
   from (pry):7:in `+'
```

**Method 4:**
       When Array contains an nil and empty values, by default if you use any above functions reduce, sum, inject everything will through the

> TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer

You can overcome this by,

```
   [16] pry(main)> sum = 0 
   => 0
   [17] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,nil, ''].each{|a| sum+= a.to_i }
   => [1, 2, 3, 4, nil, ""]
   [18] pry(main)> sum
   => 10
```

**Method 6:**
      **eval**

Evaluates the Ruby expression(s) in string.

```
  [26] pry(main)> a = [1,3,4,5]
  => [1, 3, 4, 5]
  [27] pry(main)> eval a.join '+'
  => 13
  [30] pry(main)> a = [1,3,4,5, nil]
  => [1, 3, 4, 5, nil]
  [31] pry(main)> eval a.join '+'
  SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
  1+3+4+5+
```

Comment: `reduce` and `inject` are literally the same thing. If you really want to build an object by yourself, you should consider [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object) instead of `each` (Method 4). Suggestion: `[1,2,3,4,nil, ''].each_with_object(0) {|a| sum+= a.to_i }`

Answer (score 1):

If you feel golfy, you can do

```
eval [123,321,12389]*?+
```

This will create a string "123+321+12389" and then use function eval to do the sum. This is **only for golfing purpose**, you should not use it in proper code.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it in easy way

```
def sum(numbers)
  return 0 if numbers.length < 1
  result = 0
  numbers.each { |num| result += num }
  result
end
```

Comment: This is very non-idiomatic Ruby, it looks like Ruby written by a C programmer. In Ruby, `inject` or `sum` are preferred.

Answer (score -10):

You can use *.map* and *.sum* like:

```
array.map { |e| e }.sum
```

Comment: What is the point of do a map returning same element? this is exactly the same than `array.sum`