# refactoring ruby method

Tags: ruby, loops, refactoring

this is a simple question...

Does this method can be refactored?

```
def sum
  total = 0
  [1,2,3,4].each do |num|
    total += num
  end
  total
end
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Questions where you're asking for suggestions to refactor and/or improve existing code are better suited for the new [code review stackexchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) than stackoverflow. Consider asking similar questions there in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[1,2,3,4].inject { |total,num| total= total+num }
```

OR as per suggestion below it should be

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(0) { |total,num| total+num }
```

Comment: The assignment in `a = a+b` is unnecessary and misleading. It should just be `a+b`. Also to be equivalent to his code it should be `inject(0)` (otherwise the result is different for the empty array).

Comment: Updated the answer as per your suggestions.Thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

You can use this:

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(0, :+) # => 10
```

Comment: `[].inject(:+)` will return `nil`. What's wrong with that? Why do we need `0` instead of `nil`?

Comment: a) Because it's what the OP code does, b) because the sum of the empty set is 0 according to any definition I've ever read and c) you can't do arithmetic on nil so a return value of nil just isn't useful.

Comment: To elaborate on point c: I would expect something like `balance - sum(items_bought.map(&:price))` to evaluate to `balance` if `items_bought` is empty, not raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
>> [1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0) { |acc, x| acc + x }
=> 10
```

Or simply:

```
>> [1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0, :+)
=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the following [How to sum array of numbers in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby)