# Rails Arel, counting value of an include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I am mostly used to writing plain sql for things but I would like to understand arel better. Basically what can I do to count the contents of an :include.

```
Category.includes(:discussions)
```

That is my include then discussions has_many comments. I need to know how to count the comments of the category model.

Sorry if this is blatantly obvious and thanks for any help in advance!

Edit: Updated for count on category not discussion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your models please? Is it Category has_many Discussion has_many Comment? And are you trying to get the total number of comments for a Category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm far from an Arel expert, but my instinct as that you have to get at least a little bit manual in your calculations.  Here is how you can get the count for each category making maximal use of arel:

```
Category.joins(:discussions => :comments).group('categories.id').select('categories.id, COUNT(*) as cnt')
```

Note that you won't have the full model for categories loaded, but I think this is the fastest way to get the full list of counts.  I'm not sure what other approaches you could take with arel, but I think this is the fastest query.  Depending your specific application you might want to do things a bit differently.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will give this a try too. Hard to find the 'best' way of doing this!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use the `#count` method on any `has_many` association to get the count. For example:

```
Category.find(1, :include => :discussions).discussions.first.comments.count
```

Edit:

A "brute force" approach to counting all the comments on a particular Category:

```
category = Category.find(1, :include => { :discussions => :comments })    # Check that this eager loading doesn't cause unnecessary overhead.
count = 0
category.discussions.map{|d| count += d.comments.count}
```

Note that this will create N+1 queries and therefore might not be a performant option. An alternative is to set a [counter cache column](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) on the Discussion model and then do this instead:

```
category = Category.find(1, :include => :discussions)
count = 0
category.discussions.map{|d| count += d.comments_count}
```

Edit (2):

You can further simplify the summation bit by using the `Array#inject` method. See example here: [How to sum array of numbers in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby)

Comment: Sorry that would have been correct from what I originally explained, what I want to do is to count the comments of the category on a whole and not just the first discussion.

Comment: That was not clear from the question. You asked: "I need to know how to count the comments of the discussion model." Hence my comment for clarification on the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions, I think to save on requests I may use a post count in the tables itself with some testing. category.comments.count did not work at first, not sure why but it is working now. I will try to implement your solutions too and compare performance. Thanks!