# Getting the sum of a float of numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `0.0 24.0 0.0 12.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0` how do i get the sum of these values? .sum etc do not work on floats

EDIT:

Im doing

```
<% @data.each do |data| %>
    <%= data[ :values ]%>
<%end%>
```

Where `data[:values]` prints 
`[5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`
`[4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` 
`[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` 
and i only want to get the first value of each array and sum them together to get 10.0

@data prints

```
[{:name=>"BMW", :values=>[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}, {:name=>"Asda", :values=>[32.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sum array members in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby) ... sorry, only realized that after answering.

Comment: could you post a sample `@data` content? and how do you use `inject`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming they are in an array, this works:

```
irb(main):001:0> [0.0, 1.0, 3.0].inject(:+)
=> 4.0
```

Edit: from your edited question, it appears you want:

```
@data.reduce(0) { |sum, x| sum += x[:values][0] }
```

Which grabs the first (0th) element of each :values, and sums them all together:

```
irb(main):003:0> @data
=> [{:values=>[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], :name=>"BMW"}, {:values=>[32.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], :name=>"Asda"}]
irb(main):004:0> @data.reduce(0) { |sum, x| sum += x[:values][0] }
=> 32.0
```

Comment: undefined method `inject' for 0.0:Float

Comment: Ahmet, you should be calling inject on the array not on an individual float

Comment: Edited question please recheck for me

Comment: @Ahmet: I'm not sure what you're asking now. Does `@data.inject(:+)` give what you want? I'm not familiar enough with RoR to know for sure what you're asking.

Comment: Provided you call this on the Array, this should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
irb(main):001:0> values = [[1.0,0.0],[2.0,0.0],[3.0,0.0]]
=> [[1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 0.0], [3.0, 0.0]]
irb(main):002:0> values.map(&:first)
=> [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
irb(main):003:0> values.map(&:first).inject(:+)
=> 6.0
```

Revised:

```
@data.map {|hash| hash[:values].first}.inject(:+)
```

Comment: undefined method `first' for 0.0:Float i dont know why its saying this?

Comment: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [23.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [32.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [123.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  Is what is getting printed out

Comment: Your code shows that you are using an array called `@data`.  Try this on that object, as in `@data.map(&:first).inject(:+)`.  Also, tell me what `@data.class` tells you.

Comment: .class says Array, I've editted my question with the outputs of @data (&:first) gets the name which i do not want

Comment: Wow... Okay, so you first will need to extract the values.  `@data.map {|hash| hash[:values].first}.inject(:+)`

However, from what I'm seeing, I don't think you really want just the first value from your `values` array.

Answer (score -1):

If you have array of them:

```
[0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0].reduce(:+)
```

If not - use +.

```
0.0 + 24.0 + 0.0 + 12.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0
```

=> 36.0 
Or i miss something?

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to get the sum in some fancy way, or is it okay to do it in a loop?

I would do it like the following:

```
sum = 0
array.each do |a|
  sum+=a
end
```

Comment: There are much better ways to to this in ruby. See `Array#reduce`.

Comment: There much better ways to do this in pretty much any language that isn't BASIC.