# How to do array addition in a smart way?

Tags: ruby, arrays, math, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sum array members in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby)

Lets say I have this array

```
@test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then I want to do:

```
@test[0] + @test[1] + @test[2] + @test[3]
```

Is there not a smarter, faster way of doing this?

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@test.inject(:+)
```

Comment: folds need the identity as initial value : `@test.inject(0, :+)`

Comment: Not with ruby, if you don't supply an initial value, it uses the first value in the collection as the initial value: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html

Comment: @tokland: "If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then uses the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo." (from [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) )

Comment: More directly: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Comment: jesse, steenslag: not for empty inputs: `[].inject(:+)`. I guess the OP wants a generic solution, not for 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
@test.each { |el| sum+=el }
```

Comment: that's ok for a lot of (imperative) languages, but in Ruby the (functional) `Enumerable#inject` is the idiomatic solution.