# ruby array input

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to write a small function with ruby that gets fed a array from the user and then sums up the data in the array. I have written it as

```
    def sum(a)
      total = 0
      a.collect { |a| a.to_i + total }
    end
```

The function then runs through a rspec, which tests it by initially feeding into it a blank array. This this causes the following error

```
    sum computes the sum of an empty array
    Failure/Error: sum([]).should == 0
    expected: 0
        got: [] (using ==)
```

So its telling me that when it feeds the blank array in, its supposed to get 0 but instead its getting the array. I tried putting in a if statement written as

```
    def sum(a)
      total = 0
      a.collect { |a| a.to_i + total }
      if total = [] then { total = 0 end }
    end
```

but it gives me an error saying

```
    syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => (SyntaxError)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [How to sum array of numbers in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby)

and here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

```
def sum(a)
    array.inject(0) {|sum,x| sum + x.to_i }
end
```

Comment: this worked, thank you. Does it work because it is telling the program to add a zero to each location if that location is blank?

Comment: It converts every location to an integer. If it's blank, then it converts to zero.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `map`/`collect` for this. `reduce`/`inject` is the appropriate method

```
def sum(a)
  a.reduce(:+)
  # or full form
  # a.reduce {|memo, el| memo + el }

  # or, if your elements can be strings
  # a.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
end
```

Comment: This fails for arrays like `a = ["123","23","345","678"]`. I think Mike F is using `.to_i` specifically.

Comment: How does `a.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)` perform with memory usage on large arrays? Would it double the memory usage, or is Ruby smart enough to do this smarter?

Comment: In ruby 2.0 this could be made lazy. In previous versions, yes, it will create a temp array. Your version is more efficient in that sense. But mine is prettier :)

Answer (score 0):

```
gets.split.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
```