# Using Instance Variable to do Calculation

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

So I want to use instance variables to do something like

```
@array.each {|x,y|x+y}
```

It doesn't seem to be working, and I'm wondering if that is the correct syntax to use with an instance variable, or should it be something like

```
@array.each |x, y| x+y
```

or

```
@array.each [|x,y| x+y]
```

Do I need to use `yield` for this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: In general terms, there's no difference between a local and a instance variable, except for its scope. You can use it the very same way.

Comment: You most likely meant `inject`:  @array.inject(0){|x, y| x + y} yields the sum of all elements in the array.

Comment: It doesn't work...I expect it to at the elements in the array and add the first to the seocond, and so on, until all of the elements are added.

Comment: I'll try the inject method - the could be what I was forgetting. Is there a way to do this without inject?

Comment: I think you need to provide sample input and output. Your expectation is not clear.

Comment: What's wrong with `inject` that motivates you to use another way?  You could use `each_with_object` (or `each.with_object`) to do something similar in a more verbose fashion...  but to what end?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby

Comment: what's wrong with `array.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }`?

Comment: What about yield? When does that become necessary?

Comment: @modulus I believe you're asking too many questions all at once :) BTW you don't need to use `yield`.

Comment: You could have ruled out the two alternatives you mention but just trying them in IRB or Pry.  I certainly hope you are using one of those tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, there's no difference between a local and a instance variable, except for its scope. You can use it the very same way.

The problem with your code is that there's no each with two variables (`x` and `y`, in your example) for arrays.

You can do either:

```
total = 0
@array.each { |x| total += x }
```

Or:

```
total = @array.inject(0) { |tot, x| tot += x }
```

Or:

```
total = @array.inject { |tot, x| tot += x }
```

Which can be written also like this:

```
total = @array.inject(:+)
```

Comment: You don't actually need to set the initial value for inject.  `tot` will automatically be loaded with the first array element, and the block will execute for each remaining array eement.

Comment: You also don't need the `+=` with inject. The result of the block evaluation becomes the next memo value, so `@array.inject {|tot, x| tot + x}` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one variable within the block:

```
@array.each { |x| ... }
```

The method `each` will traverse the array one by one.

Comment: The inject works, and I can use the syntax you've listed to solve another issue that i have, since it is targetted at working with each instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `inject`:

```
@array.inject(:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the elements (which seems to be your purpose).

```
@array.inject(:+)
```