# ruby - get all values for particular key from JSON string

Tags: ruby, json

this is pretty straight forward im sure, but im feeling braindead right now, and can't figure this out....

I have this JSON response, and just want to grab all the values for the key "price", and dump them all into an array, so i can get the average for both of them.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "network": "DOGE",
    "prices": [
      {
        "price": "0.00028055",
        "price_base": "USD",
        "exchange": "bter",
        "time": 1407184167
      },
      {
        "price": "0.00022007",
        "price_base": "USD",
        "exchange": "cryptsy",
        "time": 1407184159
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

this is my code thus far:

```
data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response)
        status = data["status"]
        if status == "success"
          total = ......what do i need to do here?...
       end
```

thanks in advance
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to sum array of numbers in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-of-numbers-in-ruby)

Except you yield a hash, not a number. So you drill in.

And since the values are strings, you have to convert them to floats to do math.

```
total = data["data"]["prices"].reduce(0.0) do |sum, hash|
  sum + hash["price"].to_f
end
```

Out of curiosity, how were you stuck? What was the logical gap in your understanding that prevented you from finding a solution?