# "grains of wheat on a chessboard" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> There are 64 squares on a chessboard. Every square has the double that
>   the one before. Write a program that shows:
>   - how many grains were on each square, and
>   - the total number of grains

My code is working for the first part, but I have problems declaring the total. 
Some basic class/method declaration that I am missing. 
Thanks for helping.

```
class Grains

  def square(n)
    array_of_grains = []
    (0..63).each {|x| array_of_grains << 2**x}
     n = n-1
    array_of_grains[n]
  end

  def total
     array_of_grains.each {|x| sum += x }
  end

end
```

Comment: As an aside, use map: `arrays_of_grains = (0..63).map { |i| 2 ** i }`

Comment: And instead of `array_of_grains.each {|x| sum += x }` use `array_of_grains.inject(:+)`.

Comment: Does it say how many grains square 1 has? Or are you to supply that information?

Comment: you start with one. here you have more info about this curious problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a meta-answer, combining all the good ideas here (upvotes all around!) into a complete solution using your class.

```
class Grains

  attr_accessor :array_of_grains

  def initialize(n = 1)
    @array_of_grains = 63.times.with_object([n]) { |i,a| a << 2 * a.last }
  end

  def square(n)
    array_of_grains[n - 1]
  end

  def total
    array_of_grains.reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
board = Grains.new
board.square(3) #=> 4
board.total #=> 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of problems here.

First, `array_of_grains` is local to `square`. It doesn't exist outside the method. If you want it to be an instance variable on an instance of `Grain`, it needs to be `@array_of_grains`.

Second, your `total` method causes an error because there is no local `array_of_grains` variable for it to invoke `each` on.  Even if there were, `sum` would then be undefined. You need to declare `sum` and set its initial value to `0`, or simply use `inject(&:+)`, which is amongst the [oldest Ruby tricks in the book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-of-numbers-in-ruby).

Third, you're re-building your entire `array_of_grains` array every time the method `square` is invoked. You can use `||=` to only compute that value once.

Your methods should look something like this:

```
def square(n)
  @array_of_grains ||= (0..63).map {|x| 2 ** x }
  @array_of_grains[n - 1]
end

def total
  @array_of_grains.inject(&:+)
end
```

You can make your code *almost* work by the simple addition of an `attr_accessor :array_of_grains` above your methods, but that still wouldn't fix the problem with `sum` not being defined.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to write it:

```
square = 63.times.with_object([1]) { |i,a| a << 2 * a.last }
  #=> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192,
  #    16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152,
  #...
  #    2305843009213693952, 4611686018427387904, 9223372036854775808]
```

To determine the total as well (that I initially missed in the question):

```
total, square = 63.times.reduce([0,[1]]) do |(t,a),_|
  v = 2 * a.last
  [t + v, a << v]
end

total  #=> 18446744073709551614
square #=> (as above)
```

Comment: That's extremely over-wrought, and much longer than the clearer solution of `squares = (1..63).map { |i| 2 ** i }; total = squares.inject(&:+)` for no gain at all and a huge hit to readability. If I encountered this code in any codebase I worked on, I would replace it with something cleaner.

Comment: Would you fire me as well? (I put it there for educational value.)

Comment: No, I would coach you on why that's a bizarre and ugly solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `array_of_grains` available as an instance variable use `@array_of_grains`

You can also use Ruby's accessors:

```
attr_accessor array_of_grains # getter and setter
attr_reader array_of_grains # getter
attr_writer array_of_grains # setter
```

In which case you could do:

```
class Grains

  attr_accessor :array_of_grains

  def set_grains(array)
    self.array_of_grains = array
  end

  def total
    return self.array_of_grains.count
  end

end
```

Comment: I think the count method is usefull only to return the sum of number of elements that we have. We need to calculate de sum of the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
@square_of_sums = (n * (n + 1) / 2)**2
@number_of_squares = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6
```

This will still take time, but it is the math for what you are wanting to do.