# How do I get the sum of an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

When I use get.chomp and use an array ([1,2]) it outputs to a string ("[1,2]"). I want to change the string to an array so the method can work. How do I do this?

```
def sum(array) 
    array.inject(:+)
end

puts("Please enter an array.")
array = gets.chomp 

puts sum(array)
=>[1,2]
=>[1,2]
```

Comment: The code works as expected and returns 3: http://ideone.com/KIsVbs

Comment: Are you sure `sum(array)` doesn't raise an `ArgumentError` exception? The problem is that `array` is a string (`gets` returns a string). You need to pass an array to `sum`, The way to do that is `array = []; array << gets.to_i; array << gets.to_i`. Then it will work.

Comment: this question is a duplicate .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-of-numbers-in-ruby

Comment: It is not a duplicate. (At least it's not a duplicate of the question @Null cites.) The question is why the method doesn't work. It doesn't work because a string, rather than an array, is passed as the argument.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ... and arguably because the code does not check the type passed in.

Comment: @David, yes. I wasn't thinking in my first comment. The exception would be that the value of `array` (a string) does not have a method `inject` (i.e., no instance method `String#inject`).

Answer (score 1):

Your input converted into `string`, so you have to parse the `array` again before do any operation.

```
 def sum(array) 
    array = array[1..-2].split(',').collect! {|n| n.to_i} if array.is_a?(String)
    array.inject{|sum,e| sum + e }
 end
```

Output based on your input

```
> sum("[1,2]")
=> 3
```

Comment: input is not converted into string, it is a string :)

Comment: the guys putting  `[1,2]` this is not an `string` its an `array`, but the way he take input is `string`, I mean that. If you have problem with the language, its open for edit :)

Comment: `gets` returns tha input line as a string value, so no matter what you put there, it is a string.

Comment: Arguing is about opinion. Ruby's built in methods are not subject for opinionated discussion, [they are what they are](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets)

Answer (score 0):

Using the concept that anything that is not an integer when converted to integer is 0.

```
2.3.1 :069 > sum = 0
=> 0
2.3.1 :070 > a.split("").each { |x| sum += x.to_i }
=> ["[", "1", ",", "2", "]"]
2.3.1 :071 > sum
=> 3
```

OR

```
2.3.1 :106 >   sum = 0
=> 0
2.3.1 :107 > a.split("").map {|x| sum += x.to_i }.max
=> 3
```

Answer (score -1):

There's always the reduce(:+)

```
> [1,2,3].reduce(:+)
=> 6
```

Comment: Ha! `inject` and `reduce` are the same method!

Comment: Yeah @mattkc7, there are many ways to do the same thing in Ruby.